# tryCatch scope of error{}

Tags: r

this will output "no error found!" twice,

```
x<-"no error found!"
dontchangex <- function()
{
  tryCatch(
    {
      x<- "break this"+1  
    },error= function(e)
    {
      x<-"oh no :("
    })
  print(x)
}
dontchangex()
print(x)
```

Due to the scope of error{}. How do I access the parent scope from inside the error? 
Edit: I want to go up to the scope of the tryCatch, not break out into global scope. That is, this should print "oh no :(" "no error found!"

Answer (score 4):

Use `<<-`

```
x<-"no error found!"
tryCatch(
  {
    x<- "break this"+1  
  },error= function(e)
  {
    x <<- conditionMessage(e)
  })
print(x)
```

but I wonder what the use case is? Maybe you're wanting to let the user know that something has gone wrong, but use some sentinel so that you can continue processing. Then you might want to coerce the error to something less severe, either a warning() or message(), and return the sentinel from tryCatch()

```
f = function() {
    if (runif(1) > .8) stop("oops")
    TRUE
}

g = function() {
    ## on error, warn user but continue with sentinel 'FALSE'
    tryCatch(f(), error=function(err) {
        warning(conditionMessage(err))
        NA
    })
}
```

with

```
> options(warn=1)
> replicate(10, g())
Warning in value[[3L]](cond) : oops
Warning in value[[3L]](cond) : oops
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE NA NA  TRUE  TRUE
```

If you're concerned about scope, then

```
x <- 1
fun = function() {
    x <- "OK"
    tryCatch(stop("oops"), error=function(e) x <<- conditionMessage(e))
    x
}
```

with

```
> fun()
[1] "oops"
> x
[1] 1
```

shows that `<<-` assigns to the first matching symbol in the (hierarchy of) enclosing environments, so not necessarily  in the global environment.

'Enclosing' environment refers to the environment in which the function  was defined, rather than the 'parent frame' or environment from which the function was called. A more-or-less challenging test of one's understanding of the principles is to take this

```
f = function() {
    x <- 0
    function() {
        tryCatch({
            stop("oops")
        }, error=function(e) {
            x <<- conditionMessage(e)
        })
        ls()
    }
}
```

and explain the following behavior

```
> f0 <- f()
> environment(f0)[["x"]]
[1] 0
> f0 <- f()
> environment(f0)[["x"]]
[1] 0
> f0()
character(0)
> environment(f0)[["x"]]
[1] "oops"
> x
Error: object 'x' not found
```

Comment: doesn't that put x into the global scope? I just want to go up to the scope of the tryCatch, not all the way to global. I'll edit to clarify that that's what I want

Comment: @hedgedandlevered but you're wanting to print(x) outside of tryCatch, so ...? `<<-` is finding the first symbol in the enclosing scope, so not necessarily in the global environment (e.g., if all of your code were in a function f()).

Comment: the print(x) that is "outside" of tryCatch is actually in the same scope as the body of (the non-error part) of tryCatch
<<- puts it into the global scope. I just edited again to show that and clarify further.

Comment: @hedgedandlevered added to my answer to further clarify scope of `<<-` assignment, which is not necessarily the global environment

Comment: ok, so <<- just jumps up one scope level? good to know, thanks.

Comment: @hedgedandlevered: `<<-` is going to search up the frames till it find what it is looking for. This means it may or may not go up to global based on what your problem looks like. One of the reasons it is better to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

```
x<-"no error found!"
dontchangex <- function()
{
  errorFound <- TRUE
  tryCatch(
    {
      x<- "break this"+1  
      errorFound <- FALSE
    },error= function(e){}
  )
  if(errorFound) x<-"oh no :("
  print(x)
}
dontchangex()
print(x)
```

errorFound is only set to false when it doesn't break, but then we've made our own error block in the same scope when it does